# Parseval-Plancherel theorem for the Dirac delta

Tags: measure-theory, inner-products, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, parsevals-identity

My question overlaps somewhat with: [Is Plancherel's theorem true for tempered distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705527/is-plancherels-theorem-true-for-tempered-distribution)

I am trying to better understand the answer provided there, and have some additional questions.
Let $S$ be a tempered distribution and $f$ be a Schwartz function. Then the following identity holds:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\hat{S}(x)f(x)\,dx = \langle \hat{S}, f \rangle = \langle S,\hat{f} \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}S(x)\hat{f}(x)\,dx$$

As far as I understood we do not have conjugation, since the identity $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is not the $L^2$ inner product. Is there a specific way to indicate the inner product without conjugation?

Let $\overline{f}$ be the complex conjugate of $f$, let $\check{f}$ be the inverse Fourier transform of $f$, and let us have the identity $\overline{\hat{f}} = \check{\overline{f}}$ - which I have derived here: [Fourier transform of conjugate function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373154/fourier-transform-of-conjugate-function). Then:

$$\langle \hat{S},\hat{f} \rangle_{L^2} = \langle \hat{S},\overline{\hat{f}} \rangle = \langle \hat{S}, \check{\overline{f}} \rangle = \langle S, \overline{f} \rangle = \langle S, f \rangle_{L^2}$$

What are the assumptions for this to hold beyond $S$ being a tempered distribution and $f$ being a Schwartz function? Can the $C^{\infty}$ requirement be relaxed to allow for discontinuities over sets of measure zero? I am particularly interested if anything more can be relaxed in the case where $S$ is a Dirac delta.

Can a specific meaning be attached to the conjugation of a tempered distribution? Notably a user clarified that this can be done for the Dirac delta $\delta_y^* = \delta_{-y}$: [Conjugate of Dirac delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373078/conjugate-of-dirac-delta)

I am asking since, in general, I would like to be able to swap the places of $S$ and $f$ while the above identity should still hold:

$$\langle \hat{f}, \hat{S} \rangle_{L^2} = \langle f, S \rangle_{L^2}$$

Additionally, I am led to believe that if we have tempered distributions $S$ and $T$, then the following doesn't always make sense:

$$\langle \hat{S}, T \rangle = \langle S, \hat{T} \rangle$$

But in the case of $S(x) = \delta_y = \delta(x-y)$ and $T = \delta_z$ the expression seems to be well formed, specifically:

$$\langle \hat{\delta}_y,\delta_z \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y \rangle)\delta(x-z)\,dx = \exp(-2\pi i \langle z, y \rangle) = $$
$$= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(x-y)\exp(-2\pi i \langle z, x \rangle)\,dx =\langle \delta_y,\hat{\delta}_z \rangle$$

Additionally while $\langle \delta_y, \delta_z \rangle$ seems to make no sense, on the other hand we have:

$$\langle \hat{\delta}_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y+z \rangle)\,dx = \delta(y+z)$$

which seems to be defined. Is there anything that generalizes and formalizes this?

Comment: Again $\langle \hat{\delta}_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y+z \rangle)\,dx = \delta(y+z)$ doesn't make any sense. Do you understand that with $f_N(y) = \int_{-N}^N e^{2i \pi x y}dx$ then $\lim_{N \to \infty} f_N$ converges only in the sense of distributions ? ie. $\forall \phi \in C^\infty_c, \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle f_N, \phi\rangle = \phi(0)=\langle \delta, \phi\rangle$.

Comment: @reuns Which of the equalities does not hold and why? The right-hand side is simply $\hat{1}(y+z) = \delta(y+z)$, no? And the left-hand side is simply $\langle \exp_y, \exp_z \rangle$.

Comment: There is no  "simply", a distribution isn't a pointwise function and the integral of $e^{2i \pi xy}$ diverges. So what do you mean **exactly**.

Comment: @reuns Are you saying there is something wrong with $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y+z \rangle)\,dx$? This is the Fourier transform of 1 evaluated at $y+z$. Or is the problem with $\langle \hat{\delta}_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle$? But $\hat{\delta}_y(x) = \exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y \rangle)$, and as noted $\langle \exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y \rangle), \exp(-2\pi i \langle x, z \rangle)  \rangle = \mathcal{F}[1](y+z)$. Which part specifically from all of this is wrong?

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y+z \rangle)\,dx$ diverges. Concretely look at my comment above to see how to make sense to the Fourier transform of $1$, abstractly look at my comment of your other question to see how to make sense to the Fourier transform of any distribution.

Comment: @reuns Isn't that the Fourier transform of $1$ evaluated at $y+z$ which is equal to $\delta(y+z)$?

Comment: No it is an integral which diverges. Moreover $\delta$ is a distribution not a function.

Comment: @reuns So the issue is that it converges to a distribution? Why would this be an problem? I am not trying to evaluate it at some point, $y$ and $z$ can be variables. As in $G(y,z) = \delta(y+z) = \mathcal{F}[1](y+z)$ is a distribution.

Comment: What converges to what, what do you want. The pairing of two distributions doesn't make any sense, what makes sense is for $T$ a distribution and $S$ a compactly supported distribution then $T \ast S$ is a distribution defined by $<T\ast S,\phi>=<T,S \ast \phi>$. The other things that make sense is to take particular sequences of smooth/continuous function converging to $S$ and see what happens when pairing it with a particular distribution.

Comment: I am trying to understand why $\langle \hat{\delta}_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle = \delta(y+z)$ makes no sense. If I have $f(-z) = \langle \delta_{-z}(y), f(y) \rangle = \langle \langle \hat{\delta}_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle, f(y) \rangle$, I expect that somewhere along the way there will be an illegal step if there is something wrong with $\langle \hat{\delta}_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle$. So there is no ambiguity whether it's $f(y)$ or $f(z)$, either $y$ or $z$ can be set to a constant. If it is an ill-formed expression I want to understand the reason why.

Comment: @reuns It seems like this is actually a property - refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation .
Additionally, under further constraints, it is defined even for a restricted class of test functions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere
There are a number of other mathematical publications that define the product in some sense, and numerous cases where this property is used in physics.